# Writing wchar_t to file

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm attempting to write a `wchar_t` character (wide character) to file. Currently it writes the hex code to file, and not the character.

Here's the part in the application where it's failing

```
if(capslockKey || shiftKey)
{
    // When debugging and I press 's' this becomes 'S'. It's visible in the deugging locals window.
    wchar_t upper = towupper((wchar_t)*buffer);

    if(upper != *buffer)
        // "Testing " gets written to file, but upper gets written as a hex value
        logFile << L"Testing " << upper << logFile.flush();

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I've commented the code. When debugging `upper` contains the correct character. If a lowercase `s` is pressed, it becomes `S` if shift or capslock is pressed. This works fine.

But, when writing to file `upper` gets written as a hex value. The string `Testing` gets written as normal. Outputting to stdout using `std::wout` prints the characters just fine.

How can I save the actual character to file, and not the hex value?

Thanks to Remy, I ended up with the following which works fine:

```
/*
 * Is the keypress an alpha key? This limits everything except a-z and A-Z
 */
if((p->vkCode > 64) && (p->vkCode < 91) || (p->vkCode > 96) && (p->vkCode < 123))
{
    /*
     * Are we dealing with capital letters?
     */
    if(capslockKey || shiftKey)
    {
        wchar_t upper = towupper((wchar_t)*buffer);

        if(upper != *buffer)
            logFile << (wchar_t)upper << std::flush;
    }       
    else
    {
        logFile << buffer << std::flush;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

... Although `WM_CHAR` might be a better option for my needs. Saves having to deal with issues such as whether or not shift is pressed. Or converting `VK_RETURN` to `\n`.

## Edit

Above is pointless (lowercase to uppercase part). `GetKeyboardState` and `toUnicodeEx` does it perfectly with much less hassle.

```
BYTE keyState[256] = {0};
bool keyStateResult = GetKeyboardState(keyState);
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
wchar_t buffer[5];

int toUnicodeResult = ToUnicodeEx(
    p->vkCode,
    p->scanCode,
    keyState,
    buffer,
    _countof(buffer),
    0,
    NULL
);
```

Comment: What is `logFile` to which you are writing? You are using `std::wofstream` instead of `std::ofstream`, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using wofstream. `std::wofstream logFile = logFile.open(L"log.txt", std::ios::app);`

Comment: [Keyboard input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530.aspx) is fairly non-trivial. Writing a keyboard hook is equally involved. What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Writing a keylogger is a lot more challenging than you seem to assume.

Comment: On a side note, when you want `operator<<` to flush the stream, you should be using `<< std::flush` instead of `<< logFile.flush()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
logFile << L"Testing " << upper << logFile.flush();
```

You are not passing [`flush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) itself to `operator<<`. You are actually calling `flush()` first and then passing its return value (a `basic_ostream&` reference) to `operator<<`, which is causing the hex output you see.

To properly flush the stream using `operator<<`, you need to use the [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) stream manipulator instead, which will (indirectly) call `logFile.flush()` for you without sending its returned reference to the stream output:

```
logFile << L"Testing " << upper << std::flush;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wide streams *translate* to and from a narrow character external encoding. To directly save wide text (UTF-16 encoded in Windows) you can use a narrow stream opened in binary mode. Or you can use Microsoft extension `_setmode` to set `_O_U16`-something mode on the stream, but that's non-portable, and doesn't seem to work with newer versions of MinGW g++, although it did work earlier.

---

A good alternative is to use the standard library facilities to translate the wide text to UTF-8 encoded narrow text, and save that to a narrow stream opened in binary mode. Since this is Windows it would be a good idea to save a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning. Conversely, in Unixland it's a good idea to not do that.

---

I'm unable to reproduce the hex digits effect – and you don't include code to reproduce it – but the above advice is what you need to do *anyway*, assuming that the wide text isn't restricted to plain ASCII.